# Show only once a div per user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m new in Javascript and i´m trying to do a animation a "terms and conditions" of the website, and it works!
Now I just trying to use cookies to show only once the "terms and conditions" until a new version of the "terms and conditions", but it not working!
This accept terms will be used in a wordpress site.

I don´t know what is wrong
Any tips, articles, anything else will be a great useful

```js
document.cookie="username, expires= Sat, 31 Dec 2016 12:00:00 GMT";


$('txt .avia-button').click(function()){
    if ($.cookie('#txt .avia-button')) $('#txt').animate();
    else {
        $('#txt .avia-button').click(function(){
            $('#txt').animate({ 
         bottom: '-300px',
  height: 'toggle',
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `$.cookie('#txt .avia-button')` so do you store a cookie value for that?

Comment: Alternate to using a cookie, you can use HTML5 localStorage to store a boolean if they have already read the Terms. It is a lot easier for people to block cookies than it is to block localStorage.

Comment: `$('txt .avia-button').click(function()){` is missing a `#`

Comment: `document.cookie="username, expires= Sat, 31 Dec 2016 12:00:00 GMT";` should be inside an if statement somewhere where you show your terms and conditions

Comment: You've got a click event nested inside a click event (probably not what you want)

Comment: yes! @epascarello  '$.cookie('#txt .avia-button)' will make the "terms" dissapear

Comment: @SeuZeRicardo Where do you set it?

Comment: @epascarello in a custom.js

Comment: @Korgrue i see the localStorage but in Brazil, many users don´t have a browser updated, so i prefer using cookies ... Thanks!

Comment: @RobertMcKee This 'if' is to verify that the button has been clicked, at least that's what I wanted to do

Comment: @SeuZeRicardo You know your audience far better than I do, so if you know the majority of your potential users will be hitting your site with non HTML5 compatible browsers, then yes - definitely use cookies over localStorage.

Comment: @RobertMcKee The code will be like this ?  
'$('#txt .avia-button').click(function()){
   if ($.cookie('#txt .avia-button')) $('#txt').animate();
   else {
    $('#txt .avia-button').click(function(){
     $('#txt').animate({ 
      bottom: '-300px';
      height: 'toggle';
      document.cookie="username, expires= Sat, 31 Dec 2016 12:00:00 GMT";
     });
    });
   }
  });'

Comment: How about using AJAX to query the database or whatever storage you are using to find out whether a new terms and conditions has been released. Other wise can you not use session storage to see if your terms and conditions has been shown once or more.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
if ($.cookie('seenTOS')!='1'))
{
  $('#txt').hide();
}
$('#txt .avia-button').click(function() {
    $.cookie('seenTOS','1', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    // Show #txt
    $('#txt').animate({
        bottom: '-300px';
        height: 'toggle';
    });
});
```